# Finding a normal operator/matrix from a symmetric matrix

Tags: matrices, operator-algebras

it’s well known that a matrix $A∈ M_n (R)$ has the following decomposition: 
$$A=\frac12(A+A^T)+\frac12(A-A^T)=S+K$$ with $S=\frac12(A+A^T)$  and $K=\frac12(A-A^T)$
where $S$ is the symmetric component of $A$ and $K$ is the skew-symmetric component of $A$.

Now, my problem is: given a symmetric matrix $S$, is it possible to find its skew symmetric complement matrix $K$ so that the resulting matrix $A=S+K$ is normal or at least belong to a sub-class of normal operators (quasi normal, subnormal, hyponormal or even paranormal).

$\def\Com{\operatorname{Com}}$
Recall that a matrix (or the corresponding linear operator) is

- Normal if its self-commutator $\Com(A)=AA^T-A^T A=0$ or if $\Com(S,K)=SK-KS=0$
- Quasi normal if $\Com(A,A^T A)=A(AA^T)-〖(A〗^T A)A=0$
- Hyponormal if $\Com(A)=AA^T-A^T A>0$

Comment: There are no hyponormal matrices, so that can be ruled out

Comment: Please format your question correctly.  [Here is a page](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/5020/81360) that explains how formatting on this site works.

Comment: Note also that the notions of quasinormal and normal coincide for matrices

Comment: Your problem poorly stated. If we take $K = 0$, then $K$ is skew symmetric the resulting matrix $S + K$ is normal.  In order to find "the" skew symmetric complement, you will need to put some conditions on $K$.